# folder structure

Tags: php, html

I was wondering what is the best way to set up my directories or pages. I have a public directory, and a user directory. The public dir is for general usage, and the user section is for logged in registered users. 
the directory is set up like this

```
root/
  /public
    index.php
    /user
      index.php
```

Inside the user directory i use for voting and leaving comments on different things, and the public area is just for general browsing. I prefer it set up this way. Am i going about this the right way, or should i move the user area out so that it's next to the public folder? 
Also, is there a way to do a mod rewrite not to show which folder you are in but not show it it in the url?

Answer (score 1):

```
/web-root/index.php
/web-root/images/heneral/
/web-root/images/user/
/web-root/images/news/
/modules/general.php
/modules/user.php
/modules/news.php
/templates/general.tpl.php
/templates/user.tpl.php
/templates/news.tpl.php
```

Comment: that's mostly how it's already set up. already except that the public is in a directory off of the web-root, and the user's directory is inside of that.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how far you want to go with everything. Tough to say exactly in my opinion without some background info. To be honest I would set everything up in a MVC. Personally, I have been using the Yii framework and I love the way everything is organized.

Comment: I'm building a community site. I don't think that it will get huge, but there will be a place for jokes, pictures, videos. right now there is a public section that is stripped down pretty much, and then there is a user section, with a lot more features added in. the user section is pretty much cloned copies of the public section, but with more code for the features. MVC's confuse me to no end, but i have to admit, i haven't really looked into them all that much either.

Comment: Casper I am guessing by your level of reputation on here that your pretty new to programming like me. Ive been in web development for lots of years but newer to actual programming. using a framework was the best decision I ever made. I would be happy to help you out if you want to get in touch via skype or something.